# How do I import Progressbar.js in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I'm trying to use [this progress bar](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install) in Laravel 5.6. According to Progress.js docs, you do the following:

```
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js')
```

In the default `assets/js/bootstrap.js` file I have:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
```

But I still get `progressbar is undefined` when I attempt to use it in the front end. Lodash & Popper are accessible.

When I hover over `window.ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');` in VCS, it says:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'progressbar.js'.
>
> '/Users/proevilz/sites/stream-raiders/node_modules/progressbar.js/src/main.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm install
>   @types/progressbar.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
>   file containing `declare module 'progressbar.js';`

I did what it suggested but got an error from NPM stating there is no types.

The `main.js` contains:

```
module.exports = {
    // Higher level API, different shaped progress bars
    Line: require('./line'),
    Circle: require('./circle'),
    SemiCircle: require('./semicircle'),

    // Lower level API to use any SVG path
    Path: require('./path'),

    // Base-class for creating new custom shapes
    // to be in line with the API of built-in shapes
    // Undocumented.
    Shape: require('./shape'),

    // Internal utils, undocumented.
    utils: require('./utils')
};
```

What am I doing wrong exactly? Can I load this package in without explicit referencing the `progressbar.js` file in my HTML file?

Comment: I m not sure but use npm command to install the progress bar library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After helping a bit more on a stream, it looks like the issue was that it was not saved as a dev dependency, but instead as a regular dependency. Moving it over in the `package.json` file and running `npm install` was the fix.